# UIScrollView & AutoLayout - UIScrollView Over scrolling (showing excessive whitespace at bottom)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a login page with a bunch of elements on it:

- UIScrollView
- Content View (UIView)

  - Email Text Field
  - Password Text Field
  - Login Button
  - Etc.

I need my app to run perfectly in both portrait and landscape orientations so I began setting up the different constraints to get AutoLayout working properly. I finally have all my UI elements in the right positions for both Portrait and Landscape, but the issue is that my scroll view scrolls too much and leaves a lot of empty white space at the bottom of the view when fully scrolled. I would like to fix this and keep things tight but I am not sure why. It's clearly the contentSize of the scrollview that is being set too large for the y value but I do not want to fix this with a  workaround programmatically as I'm sure there should be the "correct" fix out there.

I've attached screenshots of the login page normal and fully scrolled (portrait and landscape) to help further understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Fully Scrolled ScrollView - Notice the extra white space at bottom]

Comment: Read [Tech Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).  You might also find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the height of scroll view, you need to do these two things:-

1. In the size inspector of scroll view, change the intrinsic size to "PlaceHolder".
2. Make sure you have added enough constraints that height of scroll view can be calculated. Since the contents in your scroll view are of static height, you can simply add a height constraint to your scroll view.

Comment: UPDATE - After adding the height constraint and editing the bottom spacing constraint of the ContentView my problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure of this, but it could be that the view extends over the nav bar, causing the scrollview to have a much larger height than it should. IF that is the case, then autolayout-ing your view cause elements to be displayed everywhere else, other than the places you want them to be.

You'll need to disable Extends Under Top Bars in the attributes inspector.

Comment: I can't find the 'Extends Under Top Bars' option in the attributes inspector for the scroll view

Comment: @Mike Simz, choose your view controller > choose the attribute inspector > under Extended Edges you will find "Under Top Bars"

Answer (score 0):

I too had problem with scrollview my problem was that in iOS8 the scrollview was leaving some white space from top. I got crazy, finally I saw the solution by Ali Awais in this post and it fixed it

Here is the solution and link by Ali

*I faced the same issue in iOS 8, following is solution I found: - Select View Contoller (in storybord) in which you have added the scroll view - In "Property Inspector" in "Layout" section un-check "Adjust Scroll View Insets"*

[White space scroll view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047595/extra-top-white-space-since-ios-8-using-autolayout-and-scrollview)

-anoop